# print referred variable from object in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In the below python code ,can the object know that the template tag is referring a variable and get that in a python variable

`newemp` is the object that i am passing from the views and the template is trying to access a variable as `{{newemp.get_names.emp_add}}` ,now in the python code can the object print this variable i.e, `emp_add`

```
class Emp(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def get_names(self):
     logging.debug(var)          
      var=self.some referred object

     names = {}
```

Comment: I'm no sure what you're asking. Do you want to log 'newwemp'?

Comment: want to log emp_add as a string..

Answer (score 0):

No. The access is done once the appropriate object has been returned from `get_names()` so there is no direct way to know within the method what is being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can write to a variable within a template, and then access that value back within your Python code, I do not believe so.  That kind of goes against the idea of templates, IMHO.